# Creating .deb with systemd service but without SysV init scripts

Tags: debian, systemd, init.d, packaging, deb

I'm trying to add a systemd service file to an existing Debian package. I followed https://wiki.debian.org/Teams/pkg-systemd/Packaging, so I created `debian/packagename.service`. Because my `debhelper` is version 9.x, I also:

- added `dh-systemd` to `Build-Depends` in `debian/control`
- added `--with systemd` to the `dh` command in `debian/rules`.

Now when I rebuild the package with `debuild -i -us -uc -b`, it fails with this output:

```
Now running lintian...
[...]
W: packagename: init.d-script-not-marked-as-conffile etc/init.d/packagename
E: packagename: init.d-script-not-included-in-package etc/init.d/packagename
```

It seems like the build script expects an init.d script if there is a `.service` file. And indeed, the generated `DEBIAN/postinst` includes this section:

```
# Automatically added by dh_installinit
if [ -x "/etc/init.d/infinoted" ]; then
        update-rc.d infinoted defaults >/dev/null
        invoke-rc.d infinoted start || exit $?
fi
# End automatically added section
```

Is this expected behavior? Should I always include SysV init scripts when I include a `.service` file? If not, what is the recommended way to prevent the generation of this section?

My system is Debian Jessie.

Answer (score 0):

Overriding `dh_installinit` worked for me. I just added this to `debian/rules`:

```
override_dh_installinit:
        true
```

It still installs the systemd unit and everything seems to work as expected.

But I still don't know if this is expected behavior or a bug. Note that I did not test this on Debian Stretch or Sid, only on Jessie.